# Como guardar una SELECT MySQL en una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen día programadores,

Les pido de su ayuda para poder lograr el objetivo que quiero, tengo una tabla en MySQL donde se aprecia un kardex entradas y salidas, realice un SELECT para sumar las entradas con las salidas y que me arroje el Stock actual, me gustaría que los datos de ese SELECT se guardarán en una tabla y se actualizará si hay cambios en la tabla a la cual le estoy realizando el SELECT.

Agradezco su ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que querés es poder ver siempre los resultados actualizados, en lugar de una tabla podes crear una `VISTA` (`VIEW`) con ese query, y luego usar la vista como si fuera una tabla.

Si lo que querés es poder guardar una foto de la tabla en un momento dado en otra tabla podés hacer un `CREATE` `<tabla_nueva>` `AS SELECT` `<query>`.

[Documentación de Create View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html)
[Documentación de Create Select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html)

Comment: Juan, Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya pude cumplir mi objetivo usando una vista.